# Printing out hashed values?

Tags: javascript, meteor, hashcode

I am trying to print out an int that I applied a sha256 hash to, but am only getting [object Object] in the server logs.

Any ideas for how to print / view the object?

```
Meteor.methods({
twilioTest:function () {

console.log("Twilio Test Called!");

    // Get time for 2fa code
    var d = new Date();
    var seconds = d.getTime() / 1000;
    seconds = parseInt(seconds);

    // Get large random int
    var largeInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999999 - 99999999999999999) + 99999999999999999);

    console.log("seconds value: " + seconds);
    console.log("largeInt value: " + largeInt);

    // Combine the values
    var combined = seconds + largeInt;

    console.log("combined value: " + combined);

    // Hash the value
    combined = Meteor.call('generateHash',combined);
    console.log("combined value HASHED: " + combined);

},

generateHash: function(val){
    check(val, Match.Any);
    var hash = 0;

    var crypto = Npm.require('crypto');
    var key = 'abc123';

    hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);

    return hash;
}
});
```

Comment: Try to `JSON.stringify` that object into console and see if it contains properties with desired values. And check if this object provides a method to output string value. There surely has to be one.

Comment: I gave that a shot, the output was: " {"_binding":{}} "
Very puzzled by this...

Comment: You know that you're not creating hash out of value right? And except for that, you're getting object, because `crypto.createHmac` creates an hmac object...

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to meteor. Any advice on how to properly hash the value?

Comment: Just a side note, use console.log(foo) where foo is your object, and it will stringify the json for you. If you do console.log("Here is the value of foo: " + foo) it will just print out it's data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the way I was hashing the value. First I made sure to typecast my int to a string, then this is how the hash should have been generated:

```
generateHash: function(val){
    check(val, Match.Any);
    var hash = 0;

    var crypto = Npm.require('crypto');
    var key = 'abc123';

    hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(val).digest('hex') // This line is key

    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.call() does not return a value in the way that you're expecting; you need to check the callback. Use something like this:

```
Meteor.call('generateHash', function(error, hash) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(hash);
    }
});
```